# In scala 2.11+ how to use exactly the singleton type as type evidence?

Tags: scala, singleton, implicit, singleton-type

I'm writing a math library for complex vector computing, part of which looks like this:

```
object Example1 {

  val two = 2
  val three = 3

  // SU means 'special unitary group'
  trait SU_n[D <: Int] {

    def plus(v1: ComplexVector[D], v2: ComplexVector[D])(
        implicit ev: D =:= two.type
    ): ComplexVector[D] = {
      //TODO: some unspeakable magic here
      ???
    }
  }

  class ComplexVector[D <: Int: ClassTag](xyzw: List[(Double, Double)]) {

    {
      assert(xyzw.size.isInstanceOf[D])
    }
  }

  type Quaternion = ComplexVector[two.type]

  val alsoTwo = 2

  object SU_2 extends SU_n[two.type] {}
  object SU_Also2 extends SU_n[alsoTwo.type] {}

  object SU_3 extends SU_n[three.type] {}

  val q = new Quaternion(List(1.0 -> 2.0, 3.0 -> 4.0))

  {
    val v2 = SU_2.plus(q, q)
    val also_v2 = SU_Also2.plus(q, q)

  }

  val vec =
    new ComplexVector[three.type](List(1.0 -> 2.0, 3.0 -> 4.0, 5.0 -> 6.0))

  // This will break
  //  {
  //    val v3 = SU_3.plus(vec, vec)
  //  }
}
```

the infix type `=:=` is used to ensure that function `plus` won't be usable on vectors other than quaternions, when I compile it, I got the following error message:

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : <mypackage>.Example1.two.type (with underlying type Int)
 required: AnyRef
  type Quaternion = ComplexVector[two.type]
```

The strange thing is that I can't find anywhere in the implementation of infix class `=:=` that mandates its operand to be `AnyVal`, so why I'm getting this error? And how to fix/bypass it to achieve the requirement? (namely, create a function that can only be applied on quaternion)

Comment: "create a function that can only be applied on quaternion" -- This is easy:
`def plus(v1: Quaternion, v2: Quaternion)`

Comment: I have to admit I'm puzzled by your design - does it really make sense to have a method `plus` on every instance of `SU_n` that can however only be actually called on `SU_2`? Why not mix in an extra `QuaternionSupport` trait, or use an implicit class to extend `SU_n[two.type]` so the `plus` method is really only available when it makes sense?

Comment: OK I'm kind of puzzled as well, the class ComplexVector wasn't generic before (it is converted from somethings similar to numpy/nd4j's ndarray), I changed it in the last minute, but you got the idea.
BTW the mixin pattern won't work due to the same conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singleton types produced by `.type` don't work in quite the way you're imagining - in particular, they're not literal types. To see this, verify:

```
val two = 2
val alsoTwo = 2
type V = two.type
type W = alsoTwo.type
implicitly[V =:= W] // will fail with an implicit error
val test : V = 2 // will fail with "expression does not conform to type"
def id(x: V) : W = x //will fail with "expression does not conform to type"
```

Historically, this `.type` syntax was only meant to be used for `AnyRef`, with the compiler not exposing singleton types for primitive types. As of 2.13, this has changed in that the language now supports literal types, but it looks like the behaviour of `.type` is still the same.

If 2.13 is an option, you can just write

```
  trait SU_n[D <: Int] {

    def plus(v1: ComplexVector[D], v2: ComplexVector[D])(
      implicit ev: D =:= 2
    ): ComplexVector[D] = {
      //TODO: some unspeakable magic here
      ???
    }
  }

  type Quaternion = ComplexVector[2]

  object SU_2 extends SU_n[2] {}
  object SU_Also2 extends SU_n[2] {}

  object SU_3 extends SU_n[3] {}
```

and everything will work as intended. If you need to stick with 2.11 or 2.12, I suggest looking at [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#singleton-typed-literals) if this is the route you want to go down.

That said, as per my comment, this seems like a very odd way of solving the problem, since the idea of having a trait `T[A] { def foo(a: A) }` where calling `foo` will only compile if `A` is a specific type strikes me as fairly pathological. If you really want a `plus` method only accessible to the quaternions, you could do something like

```
implicit class QuaternionSupport(quaternions: SU_n[2]) {
  def plus(quaternion1: Quaternion, quaternion2: Quaternion) : Quaternion = ???
}
```

and the method won't be present for other dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't upgrade to 2.13 at the moment (still have Spark dependency) but I found the similar feature in Shapeless (using Witness class), so it has no problem now